# How to modify a model after passing validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I think I have to register an Active Record callback but I don't know which one.

From what I understand, `after_validation` is called even when the validation is failed, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `before_save` for this as it only gets called if validation passes